# Memory allocation for struct (low performance)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, performance, memory-management, numerical-analysis

I do have a question related to slow performance of allocating memory for several structs.
I have a struct which is looking like: see below

```
typedef struct _node
{
 // Pointer to leaves & neigbours
 struct _node *children[nrChild], *neighb[nrNeigh];
 // Pointer to parent Node
 struct _node *parentNode;  
 struct _edgeCorner *edgePointID[nrOfEdge];

 int    indexID;                // Value
 double f[latDir];              // Lattice Velos
 double rho;                    // Density
 double  Umag;                  // Mag. velocity    
 int    depth;                  // Depth of octree element

} node
```

At the beginning of my code I do have to create a lot of them (100.000 – 1.000.000 ) by
Using :

```
tree = new node();
```

and initiating the elements after it.
Unfortunately, this is **pretty slow**, therefore do anyone of you have an idea to improve the performance?

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you'll want to fix it so that it's actually written in C++.

```
struct node
{
    // Pointer to leaves & neigbours
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<node>, nrChild> children;
    std::array<node*, nrNeigh> neighb;
    // Pointer to parent Node
    node* parentNode;  
    std::array<_edgeCorner*, nrOfEdge> edgePointID;

    int    indexID;                // Value
    std::array<double, latDir> f;  // Lattice Velos
    double rho;                    // Density
    double  Umag;                  // Mag. velocity    
    int    depth;                  // Depth of octree element
};
```

Secondly, in order to improve your performance, you will require a custom allocator. Boost.Pool would be a fine choice- it's a pre-existing solution that is explicitly designed for repeated allocations of the same size, in this case, sizeof(node). There are other schemes like memory arena that can be even faster, depending on your deallocation needs.

Comment: Of course, there's a good chance that this won't work with his compiler, and an even better chance that it won't have the correct semantics if it does.  (The use of `unique_ptr` is probably _not_ the correct solution.)

Comment: It's tagged VS2010, so there's an excellent chance that it will work with his compiler, and have the intended outcome.

Comment: Hello Guys,

because I was interested in using the Boost.Pool library to see the performance difference, I tried to do the same <br> <br>
    `tree = new node();` <br> <br>
with the boost pool library, like “DeadMG” suggested by using the  <br> <br>
    `boost::fast_pool_allocator;` <br> <br>
The problem is now I do not know the syntax doing the same by using boost::fast_pool_allocator.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many nodes you will have, you could allocate them all in one go:

```
node* Nodes = new node[1000000];
```

You will need to set the values afterwards, just like you would do if you did it one by one. If it's a lot faster this way, you could try an architecture where you find out how many nodes you will need before allocating them, even if you don't have that number right now.

Comment: The main issue with that is that he can't deallocate them again except all in one go.

Comment: I would be fairly trivial to create a block allocator for his nodes.

Comment: This is a possible method for me as long as I am able to add some extra elements. I just have one question: How can I get access to the first, second, etc. element to initiate the them?

Comment: The same way you would address any other zero-based array: "Nodes[0].depth = 42;"